# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when calling SQLLite method

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, exc-bad-access

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    NSString *selectQuery =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from myaccount"];

    NSMutableArray *fl =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *sname;
    NSString *myMobNo;
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [selectQuery UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            sname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            myMobNo = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)];
            [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@!%@",sname,myMobNo]];

            [fl addObject:str];

        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return fl;
```

I am using Objective C with SQL Lite in my project.When i call above method i am getting error as EXC_BAD_ACCESS at If condition.What is wrong with my code.Any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

```
  0x0003c099 -[DBModel getCName] + 112
1   Kinkey  0x0001d623 -[ChatViewController viewDidLoad] + 302
2   0x34dae579 <redacted> + 364
3   0x34e031f7 <redacted> + 26
4   0x34e0313d <redacted> + 28
5   0x34e03021 <redacted> + 32
6   0x34e02f4d <redacted> + 272
7   0x34e02699 <redacted> + 64
8   0x34e02581 <redacted> + 324
9   0x34df0b5b <redacted> + 858
10  0x34df07fb <redacted> + 38
11  0x0004cd33 -[ChatView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 970
12  0x34e5131d <redacted> + 876
13  0x34ed3da9 <redacted> + 156
14  0x3388f657 <redacted> + 450
15  0x32f55857 <redacted> + 14
16  0x32f55503 <redacted> + 274
17  0x32f54177 <redacted> + 1230
18  0x32ec723d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
19  0x32ec70c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
20  0x36aa533b GSEventRunModal + 74
21  0x34de32b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
22  0x00002a31 main + 108
23  0x000024cc start + 40



NSMutableArray *Details = [[DBModel database]getCName];
    NSArray *array = [[Details objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];
    acName = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    acMobileNo = [array objectAtIndex:1];

if ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 1)!= nil) {
        sname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt4, 1)];
        }
```

Comment: Has `db` been correctly initialized?

Comment: yes.It gives error irregularly.

Comment: i initialize it in DbModel.h as sqlite3 *db;

Comment: OK you'll need to provide a stacktrace.

Comment: Side note - Don't use `stringWithFormat` unless you are actually formatting a string. Your `selectQuery` should simply be: `NSString *selectQuery = @"select * from myaccount";`.

Comment: Show the stack trace!!  Identify lines in your code that correspond to lines in the stack trace.  And specify whether or not this is an ARC project.

Comment: Great, so you'll obviously have to share `getCName` (both relevant parts of its implementation and how you call it).

Comment: And can you confirm that neither the 2nd nor 5th columns of your result set can ever be `NULL`? I'd retrieve the `sqlite3_column_text` as a separate variable and make sure it's not `NULL`, before calling `stringWithUTF8String`. Passing a `NULL` to `stringWithUTF8String` will cause exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could also be caused if the `db` pointer was not pointing to a valid, open database. This can happen either if (a) you neglected to call `sqlite3_open` and the `db` pointer was not `NULL`; or (b) you closed the database at some point and neglected to `NULL` the `db` and then neglected to reopen it before trying to use it again. Bottom line, if you pass an invalid, non-NULL value to `sqlite_prepare_v2`, you'll generate a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

As an aside, you have another exception risk in this code: If one of those two text fields were `NULL` (e.g. either the database had `NULL` values or you got the column indexes wrong (e.g. being a zero-based index, `sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)` is the second column, `sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)` is the fifth column), your program would also generate an exception (though a different exception). Bottom line, you cannot pass a `NULL` value to `stringWithUTF8String` without generating an exception. I might encourage you to check those two values before calling `stringWithUTF8String`. (If you had your database defined so those columns were `NOT NULL`, that mitigates this risk a little.)

Comment: @trojanfoe Good point. According to the docs, "Using ARC, strong, weak, and autoreleasing stack variables are now implicitly initialized with `nil`." Other pointers are probably not reliably `NULL`. I've altered my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is happening irregularly.Are u sure this might be reason?

Comment: I am open the database in init method.I did not close it anywhere

Comment: @user2381789 There are very few ways to get that exception in response to a `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, and, yes, this is definitely one way. That, or possibly an invalid pointer for the second parameter, which does not seem possible on the basis of your code snippet. I'd definitely search through the whole project for any references to any `sqlite3` to make sure none have slipped your attention. If you want to upload your project somewhere, I'm happy to take a peek and see if I see anything.

Comment: please let me know if u find any solution

Comment: @user2381789  OK, but people have asked you for all sorts of things (stack track at crash, ARC or not, etc.) and you seem reticent to share. That's fine, but we can't help you unless you help us. When I'm completely stymied, I always create a simplified project that manifests the problem (either by taking a copy of the original project and pulling irrelevant things out, or by starting with blank project and adding relevant things in). Then share the simplest project that manifests the bug with us (and by the way, just going through that exercise often identifies the culprit).

Comment: this is what my stack trace:

Comment: i called that method in viewDidLoad method in chatViewController.

Comment: @user2381789 I know this is probably frustrating for you, but there simply isn't enough here for us to help you. The causes of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` are generally using some invalid reference (the bad pointer that I allude to above, etc.). And if your ARC project never uses `assign` or `__unsafe_unretained` qualifiers, then Objective-C code is unlikely to be the culprit (which is why I gravitated to the SQLite C API), which definitely can cause this exception. Maybe someone else can divine what the problem is, but I can't without seeing more of the project.

Comment: I open the DB pointer in init method in DBModel.h.I did not close it anywhere

Comment: @user2381789 If you're telling us that neither of the two likely crashes from this code are likely, namely (a) the db pointer has been opened and is still open; and (b) that the 2nd and 5th columns are never NULL, then I'm going to suggest that the crash is not likely to be in this code snippet you've provided in your question. It must rest elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you already release the object and trying to reuse without retain.

Comment: I think this memory problem.

Comment: Another method for catching EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions before they happen is the static analyzer, in XCode 4+.

Run the static analyzer with Product > Analyze (shift+cmd+B). Clicking on any messages generated by the analyzer will overlay a diagram on your source showing the sequence of retains/releases of the offending object.